# LSTM Model - [samples, timesteps, features]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, lstm

I am pretty much on day-0 trying to understand the [samples, timesteps, features] pattern when it comes to training an LSTM model.

Say we have a TIME-SERIES T with :

- T = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
- Lag / Look Back = 6

The following two sets of input - output will be calculated :

1. {[1,2,3,4,5,6] - 7}
2. {[2,3,4,5,6,7] - 8}

I get that the number of samples in this particular example is equal to 2 however some things I've noticed that work and can't understand why/how are the following on the input of the let's say (1) input-output combination:

a. Set the model's input_size as (1,6) and keep the input as is [1,2,3,4,5,6]

b. Set the model's input_size as (2,3) and transform the input to the following format [[1,2,3] [4,5,6]]

What is the difference between a and b?

Correct me if I am wrong but it seems to me that in (a) I train the NN using a 6-length input at a time while in (b) I train the NN by feeding it each input two triplets at a time. Furthermore how does this affect the NN?

Maybe (questionmark) it has something to do with the concept of memory in an LSTM model.

I am using the tensorflow.keras api by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a simple model architecture:

```
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=16, input_shape=(n_timesteps, n_features), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model.fit(X, y, batch_size=4, epochs=200, verbose=0)
```

Lets say we have the following dataset with 6 features:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'F1':np.arange(1, 21, 1),
                        'F2':np.arange(11, 31, 1),
                        'F3':np.arange(51, 71, 1),
                        'F4':np.arange(71, 91, 1),
                        'F5':np.arange(46, 66, 1),
                        'F6':np.arange(26, 46, 1)})
```

`Now consider Case A i.e. Set the model's input_size as (1,6):`

In this case, the data you are feeding the model is of the shape `(4, 1, 6)`. i.e using `1 timestep`, `6 features` and a `batch size of 4`.

Lets reshape the data to `3D input`

```
X = df.values
X = X.reshape((X.shape[0], 1, X.shape[1]))
```

As we have a batch size of `4`, your one batch will look something like this:

```
[[[ 1 11 51 71 46 26]]
 [[ 2 12 52 72 47 27]]
 [[ 3 13 53 73 48 28]]
 [[ 4 14 54 74 49 29]]]
```

`Now consider Case B: Set the model's input_size as (2,3):`

The data you are feeding the model is of the shape `(8, 2, 3)`. i.e using `2 timesteps`, `3 features` and a `batch size of 4`.

Lets reshape the data to `3D input`

```
X = df.values
X = X[:, :3] #As you are using 3 features in this case.
X = X.reshape((10, 2, X.shape[1]))
```

As we have a batch size of `4`, now, your one batch will look something like this:

```
[[[ 1 11 51]
  [ 2 12 52]]

 [[ 3 13 53]
  [ 4 14 54]]

 [[ 5 15 55]
  [ 6 16 56]]

 [[ 7 17 57]
  [ 8 18 58]]]
```

`Case C: Set the model's input_size as (2,6):`

The data you are feeding the model is of the shape `(8, 2, 6)`. i.e using `2 timesteps`, `6 features` and a `batch size of 4`.

Lets reshape the data to `3D input`

```
X = df.values
X = X.reshape((10, 2, X.shape[1]))
```

As we have a batch size of `4`, now, your one batch will look something like this:

```
    [[[ 1 11 51 71 46 26]
      [ 2 12 52 72 47 27]]

     [[ 3 13 53 73 48 28]
      [ 4 14 54 74 49 29]]

     [[ 5 15 55 75 50 30]
      [ 6 16 56 76 51 31]]

     [[ 7 17 57 77 52 32]
      [ 8 18 58 78 53 33]]
```

Comment: I appreciate the time you took to plot the provided example however it does not answer my original question. When you say batch size do you refer to the batch_size parameter of the model.fit() function? If that's the case how does the batch_size - timesteps combination affect the outcome of the NN?